# How to create a .NET Core Application having Angular7 + WebAPI + AzureAD in the same project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, angular7

In Visual Studio 2017, I know how to create an

- Angular5 solution separately in .NET Core
- WebAPI solution separately
  in .NET Core

What I am struggling to resolve is how to create a One Project which has Angular7 as Client Side App and internal WebAPI's.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of guides available for integrating .NET Core WebAPI and Angular into a single project. There is also an Angular template included in Visual Studio. Once you've created a project from the template you can upgrade the Angular version to 7. The key to integrating them is setting the path for your Angular app in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}
```

Just a couple of options for guides on doing this:

- https://neelbhatt.com/2018/12/09/angular-7-spa-crud-with-asp-net-core-and-entity-framework-core/
- https://dzone.com/articles/creating-an-angular-7-app-with-aspnet-core-a-step-1
- https://www.djamware.com/post/5cc6624980aca754f7a9d1f3/asp-net-core-sql-server-and-angular-7-web-app-authentication (This one uses forms auth)
- https://www.briankeating.net/post/Azure-AD-Angular7-net-Core-22-ADAL (includes the code for AAD setup)